# Message bus integration and resync of Bounded Contexts after downtime - Service Bus 1.0

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing, servicebus, neventstore

I have just downloaded joliver eventstore and looking to wire up a service bus with `Windows Service Bus 1.0` for an application separated across more than one Bounded Context process.

If a bounded context has been offline whilst events in other bounded contexts have been created (or may even be a new context that has been deployed), I can see the following sequence of events.

1. For an example ContextA, ContextB and ContextC, all connected using Service Bus 1.0 and each context with their own event store, they all share the same bus messaging backplane.
2. ContextC goes offline.
3. When ContextC comes back-up, other bounded contexts need to be notified of the events that need to be resent to the context that has just come back online. These events are replayed from each of the event stores.

My questions are:

1. The above scenario would apply to any event sourcing libraries, so is there any infrastructure code on top of this I can use, or do I have to roll my own?
2. With Windows Service Bus 1.0, how do I marry sequence numbers in my event store to sequence numbers on the Service Bus?
3. What is the best practice to detect and handle events that have already been received in a safe manner (protecting against message handlers failing)?

Comment: This question was more answerable before you extended it to include lots more assumptions! Having a crack though...

Comment: Anything i need to cut down on let me know and i will edit... All im really after is a way to sync offline bounded contexts and i extended with my idea. Can remove if will help clarify question

Comment: Perhaps consider chopping the event distribution across BCs (you optimising DIY pub sub impls) out of this question and asking it separately as it has little to do with event stores and is going to make it more confusing for you to get useful answers to your main question.

Comment: Regarding Service Bus 1.0, can you clarify whether you see all this as being on Azure or on premise (or hopefull not both!).

Comment: Also consider just using my rambling answer as a way for you to ask a completely new set of shorter questions that are going to be easier to answer (and ask!)

Comment: @RubenBartelink thanks :) I have chopped the question down, I can confirm all Bounded Contexts use the same messaging backplane. Each BC would replay events from its own event store when asked.

Comment: Also split off a separate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458075/windows-service-bus-point-to-point-communications-to-reduce-broadcasts

Comment: Right, before I read the question, I don't think that's a good idea, you want looser coupling than that (and a cleaner way of managing error handling and resilience).

Comment: I've added answers to your edited questions to my answer. I'd suggest we dont muck with either your question or my answer any further for everyone's sanity. Please re-ask as small a part of the question if anything is confusing or doesnt match your view of what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The above scenario would apply to any event sourcing libraries, so is there any infrastructure code on top of this I can use, or do I have to roll my own?

The notion of a Projection mechanism tied to the events is certainly common. Unfortunately, there are many many ways of handling how that might be done, depending on your stack, performance requirements and scale and many other factors.

As a result I'm not aware of a commoditized facility of this nature.

The GetEventStore store has an integrated Projection facility which looks extremely powerful and takes the need to build all this off the table. Before its existence, I'd have argued that one shouldnt even consider looking past the the SRPness of the JOES.

You havent said much about your actual stack other than mentioning Azure.

> With Windows Service Bus, how do I marry sequence numbers in my event store to sequence numbers on the Service Bus?

You can use stream id + the commit sequence number the `MessageId` (and use that to ensure duplicates are removed by the bus). You will probably also include properties in the Message metadata.

> What is the best practice to detect and handle events that have already been received in a safe manner (protecting against message handlers failing)?

If you're on Azure and considering ServiceBus then the Topics can be used to ensure at least once delivery (and you'll use the sessioning facility). Go watch the [two hour deep dive ClemensV Subscribe video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Subscribe/Service-Bus-Messaging-Deep-Dive) plus a few other episodes or you'll spent the same amount of time making mistakes)

> To keep broadcast traffic down, if ContextC requests replays from ContextA and ContextB, is there any way for these replay messages to be sent only to ContextC? Or should I not worry about this?

Mu. You started off asking whether this stuff was a good idea but now seem to have baked in an assumption that it's the way to go.

Firstly, this infrastructure is a massive wheel to reinvent. Have you considered simply setting up a topic per BC and having anyone that needs to listen listen?

A key thing here is that you need to bear in mind the fact that just because you can think of cases where BCs need to consume each others events, that this central magic bus that's everywhere will deliver everything everywhere.

---

EDIT: Answers to your edited versions of questions 2+

> With Windows Service Bus 1.0, how do I marry sequence numbers in my event store to sequence numbers on the Service Bus?

Your event store doesnt have a sequence number. It has a commit sequence number per aggregate. You'd typically use a sessioned topic and subscription. Then you need to choose whether you want a global ordering (use a single session id) or per aggregate ordering (use the stream id as the session id).

Once events are on a topic, they have a `MessageSequenceNumber` and the subscription (when sessioned) delivers (actually the subscriber recieves them) them in sequence.

> What is the best practice to detect and handle events that have already been received in a safe manner (protecting against message handlers failing)?

This is built into the Service Bus (or any queueing mechanism). You don't mark the Message completed until it has been successfully processed. Any failure leads to Abandonment (which puts it back on the queue for reprocessing).

The subscriber taking a break, becoming disconnected or work backing up is naturally dealt with by the Topic.