# Windows Service Bus Point-to-Point Communications to Reduce Broadcasts

Tags: servicebus

I am using `Windows Service Bus 1.0` to communicate between different processes, each context event stream exists on the bus as a topic.

Using the service bus to link events between bounded contexts I need a method to sync events (or in other words request a replay of past events) when a bounded context comes back online but want to limit the potential flood of messages coming back to only go to the endpoint that requested it, at least if this is something that can be easily done by using existing Service Bus features.

So given an imaginary ContextC sends a message to request all previous events from ContextA and ContextB, is there any way for these replay messages to be sent only to ContextC?

What would be the best way to map a context to be the owner of the topic (or in other words, an individual bus subscriber to a bus topic), to facilitate the unicast replaying above?

Comment: Are you trying to achieve a solution that can be deployed equally on premise or in Windows Azure?

Comment: For me the terminology is all wrong given the rest of your questions assume an event sourced CQRS architecture. Contexts should not 'Send' messages to each other, but instead they can listen to each other. Can you talk about your higher level need please? Why do the downstream consumers need to worry about all this stuff? Are you doing this to facilitate replay of events in order to 'blow away and rebuild' state in a read model within a dependent context?

Comment: Ruben thanks for the persistent help it is appreciated. Sending and replaying of events is only applicable during restore of a bounded context that has come online and wants to sync previous events- i agree with your comments as that is the same way things should happen during normal operations where we normally just listen

Comment: When you say "come online" - are you talking about spinning up an entirely fresh context which needs to event source from a partner context from the dawn of its universe? Because if you're talking about the typical sense of come on-line, i.e. dealing with 10 seconds-10 day outages that's really just normal life. If you're using any proper queueing mechanism this is the whole raison d'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my world, I keep this stuff loosely coupled - each context puts stuff onto a topic and anyone that needs stuff subscribes.

Each SB subscription can use the filtering facilities of Service Bus based on properties (e.g. you could tag events by adding Properties on the Messages and then have a filtering condition on the subscription meaning that only whitelisted classes of events ever apply to each consumer).

That plus the fact that you're already seggregating by topic.

The subscription and the topic then allow you to process the events without losing any or having the publisher go around worrying about or chasing subscribers.

You also mentioned you are tying this to an Event Store in other questions - in that case there is a chance your messages need to be consumed in order. If that is the case, you need to put a session id on your messages.

I could speculate as to why you want this subscriber driven redelivery but won't for now. You need to first explain / verify that concept and requirement (by asking questions which explain your higher level goals) a lot further before anyone answers how that would best be achieved using Service Bus.